# define in require function (requireJS)

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

(Using requireJS, angularJS, angularAMD)

When in my main.js file I have:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        'angular': 'libs/angularjs/angular.min',
        'angularAMD': 'libs/angularjs/angularAMD.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularAMD': ['angular']
    }
});

define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "udało się!";
    });
    angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
    return app;
});
```

everything works fine.
But when I cut config part to other file I got errors:

main.js:

```
require(['common'], function (common) {
    define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
        var app = angular.module("app", []);
        app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "udało się!";
        });
        angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
        return app;
    });
});
```

common.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        'angular': 'libs/angularjs/angular.min',
        'angularAMD': 'libs/angularjs/angularAMD.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularAMD': ['angular']
    }
});
```

Can I use define in require function? If not how to include common config first and then use define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `main.js` file is what you give to the `data-main` attribute on the `<script>` tag that loads RequireJS or that it is the main entry point of your application. Change `main.js` to this:

```
require(['common'], function (common) {
    require(['app']);
});
```

And create an `app.js` module in a location where your code can readily load it:

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "udało się!";
    });
    angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
    return app;
});
```

Anything that needs access to the value of `app` you create in this module can just require the `app` module.

The code you have in the question defines a module but it does so asynchronously. By the time the call to `define` happens, RequireJS has already finished loading `main`. As far as it is concerned, `main` is done. So what name should it give to the defined module?

Comment: But since I'm using angular guess I want to define app module with angular app - I cannot do it with require